# Can we have the display_name field in the /me/associated route?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, api-v2

I'm reading the [Authentication documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and I've noticed that the [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) route returns fields like `user_id`, `badges`, `reputation` but not the `display_name`, even specifying a custom `Filter`.

Once I get via `Oauth2.0` the `access_token`, the first thing I would do is to get the list of accounts of the user; without the `display_name` in the `/me/associated` route, I'm forced to make another call to the [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) route for each associated site, passing the `site` parameter on the query string .

Is this by design?
Can we have the `display_name` field in the `/me/associated` route to save some API calls?

Comment: Really it should return the full user object, and just allow you to select which fields you want using filters.

Comment: I wonder if Kevin doesn't reply because he doesn't see them (there's been a lot of Off Topic questions lately), it would be nice to be able to @ping him, from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, for reasons of technical limitations.

Unfortunately, we don't have easy access to display names at a "network level".  What's available (and what's backing the API) is very normalized, often somewhat delayed, data.

As a rule, only very small bits of data are pulled into global tables; as it all has to reside in a single database.  Generally this means no strings, like display names (or about mes, or locations, so on).

I realize this isn't ideal, but it's the world we're in until some non-trivial upgrades in our infrastructure.  Some of the necessary work is already being undertaken, but not all of it is in sight; I can't really promise changes for any particular API release.

What I suggest doing (and what the network itself does) is picking a way to choose a "primary user" and just fetching that one.  We use oldest account (backed by creation_date on network_user), though in the past we have also used highest reputation.  Either approach has its merits.

Comment: I see, but can't this be marked as _status-deferred_? Maybe in the future, after the infrastructure upgrade, this will be easier to implement and provide; after all this feature will save you from a `/me` bomb calls for each site returned from the `/me/associated` route.